# Have to create a line barcode scanner with react native cli be sure it is for barcode not for QR

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

[Capability to scan this barcode or any product barcode](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FWhat-do-the-lines-on-a-barcode-indicate&psig=AOvVaw39UU9O_ioKsM-R-bgDBQLY&ust=1664433830602000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAkQjRxqFwoTCMCJgazxtvoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use zxing library that can scan barcodes:
https://github.com/rafaeltakiyama/react-native-zxing